# Outlook 2007 pin "move to folder" options

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

In Outlook 2007 the move to folder options change based on which folder you last moved a file to.

Is it possible to fix these options to a list of folders of my choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As its Outlook 2007 I ended up using the following macro to define custom move to folder buttons for the folders I use most often.

```
' This/These macro(s) implement the procedure for different folders
Sub MoveSelectedMessagesToArchive()
    MoveSelectedMessagesToFolder ("Archive")
End Sub

' This macro does the heavy lifting, and is only called from another VBA procedure
Sub MoveSelectedMessagesToFolder(FolderName As String)

'On Error Resume Next
    Dim objFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder, objInbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace, objItem As Outlook.MailItem

    Set objNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set objInbox = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set objFolder = objInbox.Folders(FolderName)

'Assume this is a mail folder

    If objFolder Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "This folder doesn't exist!", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "INVALID FOLDER"
    End If

    If Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count = 0 Then
        'Require that this procedure be called only when a message is selected
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection(1).Class = 43 Then
    ' 43 is the literal constant for a mail item
    ' sometimes a calendar item is in the inbox, in which case there is a type
    ' conflict with the objItem variable, which is declared as a mail item.

       For Each objItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
           If objFolder.DefaultItemType = olMailItem Then
               If objItem.Class = olMail Then
                    objItem.UnRead = False
                    objItem.Move objFolder
               End If
           End If
       Next
    Else
        MsgBox ("This is not a message; it may be a calendar request")
    End If

    Set objItem = Nothing
    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set objInbox = Nothing
    Set objNS = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Quick Steps are Office 2010.
In Office 2007, the move-to-folder in the Inbox toolbar only gives the last used folder.
With the message open, however, you can click on Message to open the ribbon where there is also a Move to Folder which gives the most recent folders used. You can right-click on this Move to Folder in the ribbon and choose to add it to the Quick Access Toolbar.
You can access that quickly from the keyboard by tapping Alt and then the number corresponding to the Move to Folder in the Quick Access Toolbar.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like a job for Quick Steps.